# Is it possible to play audio in a safari browser on iphone while listening to iPod

Tags: iphone, html

I would like to allow users to play audio on my webpage while still being able to listen to their own music from their iPod app. Is this possible?

So far all my tested solutions take me out of Safari and load up Quicktime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

There's only one hardware audio decoder (for compressed mp3/aac) in current iDevices, and both Safari and the iPod app currently require it, so only one can use it at a time.

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime is the default media handler from Safari.
If I'm not mistaken, the browser does not have any kind of embedded framework to handle media. All requests get through to QuickTime.

Even if that existed, iOS, by default, does not allow two media files to be handled simultaneously. There probably isn't any official (read: not jailbroken) method to accomplish that.